# TFS Build Report Error

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild

My TFS build is deploying but I'm getting errors and a failed build google isnt returning much so I am praying someone else has seen this before.

The error I'm recieving is below:

```
Error: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\#\10151\drop\BuildReport.txt'.. Stack Trace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
   at TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.TeamFoundationServer.BuildReport.WriteToFile(String line, Int32 linebreaks) in c:\code\teambuild2010contrib\CustomActivities\MAIN\Source\Activities\TeamFoundationServer\BuildReport\BuildReport.cs:line 528
   at TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.TeamFoundationServer.BuildReport.GenerateTextReport() in c:\code\teambuild2010contrib\CustomActivities\MAIN\Source\Activities\TeamFoundationServer\BuildReport\BuildReport.cs:line 448
   at TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.TeamFoundationServer.BuildReport.GenerateReport() in c:\code\teambuild2010contrib\CustomActivities\MAIN\Source\Activities\TeamFoundationServer\BuildReport\BuildReport.cs:line 337
   at TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.BaseCodeActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) in c:\code\teambuild2010contrib\CustomActivities\MAIN\Source\Common\BaseCodeActivity.cs:line 66. 
 Exception Message: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\#\10151\drop\BuildReport.txt'. (type DirectoryNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
   at TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.TeamFoundationServer.BuildReport.WriteToFile(String line, Int32 linebreaks) in c:\code\teambuild2010contrib\CustomActivities\MAIN\Source\Activities\TeamFoundationServer\BuildReport\BuildReport.cs:line 528
   at TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.TeamFoundationServer.BuildReport.GenerateTextReport() in c:\code\teambuild2010contrib\CustomActivities\MAIN\Source\Activities\TeamFoundationServer\BuildReport\BuildReport.cs:line 448
   at TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.TeamFoundationServer.BuildReport.GenerateReport() in c:\code\teambuild2010contrib\CustomActivities\MAIN\Source\Activities\TeamFoundationServer\BuildReport\BuildReport.cs:line 337
   at TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.BaseCodeActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) in c:\code\teambuild2010contrib\CustomActivities\MAIN\Source\Common\BaseCodeActivity.cs:line 90
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Comment: Strangely removing the copy to build server option for drops and directly specifying a location the build succedes. If someone understands this I would love to be able to appreciate why this works versus just being thankful I fixed it.

Comment: This is something in TFS Build Extensions, not in TFS itself. I'd recommend reaching out to the maintainer of that project.

Comment: What's interesting to me in your stack trace is that it is looking in the system32 folder of which I am guessing is NOT where your build drops are intended to be going. Typically you would want to point it to a share or absolute path. I'm going off of my TFS 2010 knowledge.